# Perl XML parser for DOM

Tags: xml, perl, dom

I am trying to parse Performance Statistics (3gpp 32.435). The structure is not so simple as I'd wish, see example. The result I am looking for is to have a text output with

```
    endTime:measType:measValue
```

I have tried to use a perl script to extract values, but as you can see, for SGSN-MME_Session_SM_G there are two types and two values, so the result for my script is

```
     SM.SuccActSecondPdpContext.G
     SM.UnsuccActPdpContextCC38.G

        1
        473764
```

If someone could give me a hint how to parse this XML or how to join the type and value from two children of a parent. I'd be grateful, thanks..

Script used:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $filename = 'file.xml';

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $filename);

foreach my $measvalue ($dom->documentElement) {
        say $measvalue->to_literal();
    }
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="MeasDataCollection.xsl"?>
<measCollecFile xmlns="http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/specs/archive/32_series/32.435#measCollec">
   <fileHeader fileFormatVersion="32.435 V9.0" vendorName="New Vendor">
      <fileSender />
      <measCollec beginTime="2017-10-09T20:17:00+03:00" />
   </fileHeader>
   <measData>
      <managedElement localDn="TestNode" />
      <measInfo measInfoId="SGSN-MME_Mobility_U">
         <job jobId="customPdcJob" />
         <granPeriod duration="PT60S" endTime="2017-10-09T20:18:00+03:00" />
         <repPeriod duration="PT60S" />
         <measType p="1">succGprsAttachUmts</measType>
         <measValue measObjLdn="ManagedElement=TestNode,SgsnFunction=1">
            <r p="1">132737759</r>
         </measValue>
      </measInfo>
      <measInfo measInfoId="SGSN-MME_Session_DiscardedMessages_G">
         <job jobId="customPdcJob" />
         <granPeriod duration="PT60S" endTime="2017-10-09T20:18:00+03:00" />
         <repPeriod duration="PT60S" />
         <measType p="1">discardedSessionMgmnt</measType>
         <measValue measObjLdn="ManagedElement=TestNode,SgsnFunction=1">
            <r p="1">12368</r>
         </measValue>
      </measInfo>
      <measInfo measInfoId="SGSN-MME_Session_SM_G">
         <job jobId="customPdcJob" />
         <granPeriod duration="PT60S" endTime="2017-10-09T20:18:00+03:00" />
         <repPeriod duration="PT60S" />
         <measType p="1">SM.SuccActSecondPdpContext.G</measType>
         <measType p="2">SM.UnsuccActPdpContextCC38.G</measType>
         <measValue measObjLdn="ManagedElement=TestNode,SgsnFunction=1">
            <r p="1">1</r>
            <r p="2">473764</r>
         </measValue>
      </measInfo>
      <measInfo measInfoId="SGSN-MME_Session_SM_U">
         <job jobId="customPdcJob" />
         <granPeriod duration="PT60S" endTime="2017-10-09T20:18:00+03:00" />
         <repPeriod duration="PT60S" />
         <measType p="1">SM.UnsuccActPdpContextCC38.U</measType>
         <measValue measObjLdn="ManagedElement=TestNode,SgsnFunction=1">
            <r p="1">737355</r>
         </measValue>
      </measInfo>
      <measInfo measInfoId="SGSN-MME_SystemResource_PIU">
         <job jobId="customPdcJob" />
         <granPeriod duration="PT60S" endTime="2017-10-09T20:18:00+03:00" />
         <repPeriod duration="PT60S" />
         <measType p="1">SYS.gsnApCpuUsage</measType>
         <measValue measObjLdn="ManagedElement=TestNode,SgsnMme=1,PIU=1.1">
            <r p="1">6</r>
         </measValue>
         <measValue measObjLdn="ManagedElement=TestNode,SgsnMme=1,PIU=1.3">
            <r p="1">5</r>
         </measValue>
         <measValue measObjLdn="ManagedElement=TestNode,SgsnMme=1,PIU=1.5">
            <r p="1">5</r>
         </measValue>
         <measValue measObjLdn="ManagedElement=TestNode,SgsnMme=1,PIU=1.7">
            <r p="1">5</r>
         </measValue>
      </measInfo>
   </measData>
   <fileFooter>
      <measCollec endTime="2017-10-09T20:18:00+03:00" />
   </fileFooter>
</measCollecFile>
```

Comment: It looks like this question got a close vote because you started it with "I am looking for a XML parser script," which reads like you have a "give me teh codez" requirement. Posing your questions as direct questions would help avoid that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
use feature qw( say );

use XML::LibXML               qw( );
use XML::LibXML::XPathContext qw( );

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => $filename );

my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new();
$xpc->registerNs( m => 'http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/specs/archive/32_series/32.435#measCollec' );

for my $measInfoNode ($xpc->findnodes('/m:measCollecFile/m:measData/m:measInfo', $doc)) {
   my $endTime = $xpc->findvalue('m:granPeriod/@endTime', $measInfoNode);
   my $measType = $xpc->findvalue('m:measType', $measInfoNode);
   for my $measValueNode ($xpc->findnodes('m:measValue', $measInfoNode)) {
      my $measValue = $xpc->findvalue('m:r', $measValueNode);
      say join ":", $endTime, $measType, $measValue;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Just a small typo i guess, should be : for my $measValueNode ($xpc->findnodes('m:measValue',$measInfoNode))
This will bring a huge help in telco world, since i couldnt find any example of parsing this type of XMLs, and here is a ready t use solution!
By the way, to whom should i sell my soul, to get such knowledge in perl.. :)

Comment: Fixed. . . . . .